# Datatables server-side error when I click to access 5th page

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

I'm using DataTables 1.10.15.
It's working but when I click on the button to a 5th page I received this error message:
DataTables warning: table id=tabela1 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tabela1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>CPF/CNPJ</th>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Telefone</th>
<th>Celular</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th><a rel="nofollow" href="inscliente.php"><span title="Inserir"></span></a></th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>CPF/CNPJ</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Telefone</th>
<th>Celular</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabela1').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// DB table to use
$table = 'clientes';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'cpf_cnpj';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'cpf_cnpj', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'nome',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'telefone',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'celular',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email',     'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cpf_cnpj',     'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'stt',     'dt' => 6 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( '../include/ssp.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);

?>
```

Could you help with this situation?

Regards.

Comment: Most chances you trying to get page beyond rows count - so you get empty set as response.

Comment: It's funny because I have 25000 registers, with a table with 10 rows. When I click on the last page it works. But when I click on the 5th page, the error appears. I selected database to verify if is something wrong with this dataset but is normal.

Comment: Just open debug tool in chrome, and see in the network tab, what you get exactly on 5th page request. In case it is OK, you problem on client side.